# Widevine documentation

Tags: widevine

I'm trying to download the following docs from Widevine website:

- Widevine DRM for HLS: https://storage.googleapis.com/wvdocs/Widevine_DRM_HLS.pdf
- Getting Started with Widevine DRM: https://storage.googleapis.com/wvdocs/Widevine_DRM_Getting_Started.pdf
- Common Encryption API for Widevine DRM: https://storage.googleapis.com/wvdocs/Widevine_DRM_Encryption_API.pdf

But I get AccessDenied page. Is there any special authorization required to obtain them?
I tried to contact Widevine team using contact form but still got no response.

Comment: Access to Widevine documentation is now restricted to licensees. (https://www.widevine.com/news)

Comment: Seems like I tried to contact Google vie the form which is supposed to be the way to obtain a license. So I have to wait I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to Widevine documentation is now restricted to licensees. (widevine.com/news)

Comment: We've managed to implement Widevine in our server: https://wmspanel.com/nimble/drm